# Laptop display is fully white, but only in Windows

Tags: windows-7, laptop, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors

I am using an HP ProBook 4540s with Windows 7 Professional as the OS. [Specs can be found here.](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03349886)
The issue began when pressure was applied to the laptop body (on the front edge and the back of the display/lid) during use. The screen would go entirely white. Could originally be corrected by closing and opening the laptop 3-10 times successively.

Presently, the display will work perfectly during booting up and logging on, but as soon as Windows finishes loading, the display goes white. Connecting an external monitor and having the display config. set to extend or share screens allows for both the laptop and external monitors to work normally. Disconnecting the external monitor causes the laptop display to go entirely white again.

Shaking device while inverted momentarily restores the display to working order, goes white when upright again. This only rarely works now.

Graphics cards are Radeon hd 7650M as well as Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000.
Drivers appear up to date.  On the Intel card, atikmpag.sys is not digitally signed, but driver updates do not sign it.

The graphics cards appear to be interfering with each other when only using the laptop display. Disabling either graphics card causes the laptop display to function normally, but disables the external monitor. While only one graphics card is running, the laptop does not recognize any external monitor connected to it. While one card is running, the laptop display can work without being connected to another monitor.

Booting up the laptop with Linux via an external drive causes the display to function without error.

My goal is to get the laptop display to work normally while running Windows 7 professional and to no longer necessitate the use of an additional monitor while having both graphics cards running. How would I go about correcting this issue?

Comment: According to your description, it works normal in external monitor. It seems like some thing wrong with your device. I suggest you consider hardware issues first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** I opened up the settings for the Intel graphics card. At the top left there is a drop down menu for 'Select Displays'. I then set it to built-in, saved settings, reopened the drop down, and then selected built-in a second time and saved. This fixed the problem. Selecting it both times in a row was necessary. The laptop no longer requires the disabling of graphics cards in order to use the built-in display while running Windows 7.

---

I don't know why this worked now. When this whole fiasco started, it had been set to target the built-in monitor. At the time, I had never used an external monitor with it before; I hadn't even opened this menu prior to then. Swapping the graphics card setting between the external monitor and the built-in monitor was not changing anything. I have opened up this menu 50+ times these past three months and had played with this setting virtually every time in my efforts to fix this problem. This should not have worked.

Thanks to everyone for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

If shaking the device changes something, you definitely got a hardware problem (most likely but no necessarily the display). For whatever reason your linux configuration uses the display in a why that doesn't trigger the defect so there might be a "software fix" to you're "hardware problem".

First of all I would suspect the signal going to the display. What are the hard facts here like resolution etc.? If that won't give you any results you will have to go further like considering differences between the drivers you are using etc.

But there is no point speculating find out how linux is "managing the screen" and try to replicate it bit by bit with the windows configuration. Start with the easy stuff and work you're way up.

Specify you're question if you run into problems.

Comment: The laptop's resolution would be 1366 x 768. The full specs of my laptop are [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03349886).

The drivers I'm using are the ones that HP assigned to this model of the laptop, but re-downloaded  as of a week ago from their site.

Comment: No that's not what I meant. You should for example compare the resolution Linux uses to the one Windows uses. If there's a difference you should change the windows setting to the same values linux uses. If this does not help you move to the next aspect.

Comment: Settings and resolution appear to be identical. Aspect ratios appear the same.
I'm not seeing anything as far as discrepancies go between the two.

Comment: @Arpeyji If you checkt "everything" I probably checked more then I know about graphic card / display communication of the the of my head. In this case I can only advice you to specifically write down all the values you compared (including the value itself not just it's "name", so you don't overlook anything). Make sure to include the data about the graphic ship set on your laptop as well as the drivers. Maybe it will also help to know what type of monitor you are using and how it is connected to the laptop (display port etc.). Hopefully someone with deeper knowledge will be able to help you.

Comment: @Arpeyji Oh and add the data directly into you're question (edit it), don't just post it here (under my answer) as a new comment. Of course it still could be somehow related to a different cause. Although I think it's unlikely, it's still possible.

Comment: I realized that I had only use external monitor enabled. Changing that to share/extend screens demonstrated that the laptop display is functional while still connected. I then did some testing with the graphics cards (results detailed in the main post edit). I think this narrows down the possible issue substantially, most likely to interference between the graphics cards when they are trying to share a single display. Should I detail the workaround with the graphics cards in an answer and then make a separate post about graphics card interference?

Comment: No I would continue on this here, the a workaround is "only" an additional answer, unless your "final" goal has changed, I'm not sure about this.

Answer (score -1):

You've likely got a backlight out inside the screen, consequently the only fix is replacing screen. It is weird it works fine before windows, but maybe it's a timing thing. You could let it sit in BIOS for awhile to see if it acts up. It's also likely a bad connection inside that makes it sporadic. I do think it sounds hardware related

EDIT: laptop screen works in Linux fine? How long? Maybe it's in just the right spot/angle to continue working like it did after the multiple open/closes in windows? Why did you have to use external monitor to get it into Linux!?

Comment: It works without issue on Linux. I only tested for around 5 minutes, but was able to move it around without issue in this time. I then rebooted and loaded windows and the display went white as soon as windows loaded.

The Linux test and the external monitor tests were conducted independently. No monitor was connected when I did the Linux test.